# How do major countries take advantage/exploit developing countries?

Tags: international-relations

Most articles acknowledge this, and at this point I'm taking it at face value. Most sources state that it "happens," but I am trying to find some information on specifics. As in what exactly are large countries doing? Forcing low wages? I am wondering if anyone has reliable/scholarly sources for me to look through, as I am not finding any.

Secondly, if someone has any solid information that goes against this, then I be more than happy to see both sides of the story.

Thanks.

Please ask for me to clarify my question, as I tend to leave out some information/thoughts.

Comment: This question is really far too broad. You should specify which kind of "exploitation" you are talking about.

Comment: I realize that, Im just a bit frustrated trying to write a school paper. Im lacking direction and poking at the internet looking for help. What I am looking for is some sort of confirmation in terms of: Why are many developing countries they way they are? But there are limitless factors. I am trying to find a direction that is in terms of Large powers supporting dictators for their benefit. I was trying to stick to Cuba but I'm getting way off topic and lost in everything....

Comment: Rule #1 when trying to be a scientist (which "write a school paper" implies) is to not accept random statements "at face value" without proof :) That's the definition of unscientific approach.

Comment: What I have read, this is what most of the statements are saying. It comes down to the Oil companies such as the US owned ones in Cuba. Although most articles I'm finding say Cuba nationalized these, but I'm having a hard time finding the "why," or rather something more detailed.

Comment: I have no hard references for the oil companies in Cuba, but I heard in a documentary that Castro's initial relationship with the USA was ok; then the SU sent a shipload of crude oil as goodwill gesture and USA owned refineries refused to refine it; to which Castro answered by nationalizing it. For more reliable sources maybe you want to ask in history.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Since Cuba has been mentioned, it's worth looking at pre - revolution Cuba to see what abuses they felt they were suffering.

Comment: yeah thats what ive been looking at for a week now... Ive been trying to focus on what cuba did differently eith all the other countries

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did not want to answer a question so broad, but user4012's does not actually answer the question, as there are **many** claims that are not addressed:

- Advanced countries using pressure (including military) to fight developing countries from controlling their economy/resources. **LOTS** of examples here:

  - when Colombia did not agree to the conditions for the building of the Panama Canal, the USA supported the independence of Panama.
  - When Nasser nationalized the Suez Canal, UK and France prompted Israel to attack Egypt in order to retake control of the Canal.
  - Salvador Allende promoted a plan to nationalize copper mines in Chile, then under control of USA companies. Guess which country backed Pinochet's coup against Allende.
  - Mohammad Mosaddegh was less radical, he only wanted to renegotiate the deal with the British companies that exported oil and control that they were actually producing what they claimed (and paid taxes for). That did not help him either, because he was deposed by a [coup d'etat promoted by the UK and USA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1953_Iranian_coup_d%27%C3%A9tat). They left the autocratic regime of Rezah Pahlevi (the Shah of Iran), which is one of the most important motives of Iran hate and distrust of Western powers.
  - France supported the Biafran secessionist movement with the intention of [getting oil explotation contracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigerian_Civil_War#France), the UK (which had the rights given by the Nigerian government) supported the Nigerian government.
  - the list could go over and over, only with the **confirmed** interferences from Western powers to help their business at the expenses of developing countries.
- Additionally, companies from "first world" countries are known to pressure national governments (including bribes) in order to keep laws in their favor (or avoid abiding to local laws at all). This allow these to operate with reckless disregard of the rights of workers (check for United Fruit Company), population (Bhopal disaster) or environment, even in the countries were such rights exists.

To illustrate this, check what [someone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smedley_Butler#Lectures) as unlikely to be considered marxist as a **Major/General of the USMC** had to said to the effect:

> I spent 33 years and four months in active military service and during that period I spent most of my time as a high class muscle man for Big Business, for Wall Street and the bankers. In short, I was a racketeer, a gangster for capitalism. I helped make Mexico and especially Tampico safe for American oil interests in 1914. I helped make Haiti and Cuba a decent place for the National City Bank boys to collect revenues in. I helped in the raping of half a dozen Central American republics for the benefit of Wall Street. I helped purify Nicaragua for the International Banking House of Brown Brothers in 1902–1912. I brought light to the Dominican Republic for the American sugar interests in 1916. I helped make Honduras right for the American fruit companies in 1903. In China in 1927 I helped see to it that Standard Oil went on its way unmolested. Looking back on it, I might have given Al Capone a few hints. The best he could do was to operate his racket in three districts. I operated on three continents.

Of course, you will find some people that will claim that **all** of Western investment in developing countries is exploitation. user4012's answer gives a few valid arguments against people doing those claims, but does not address the fact that in many times actual exploitation has happenned or is currently happenning.

UPDATE:

As for the Mobutu example, some references to it.

- [Zaire, a country study](https://www.loc.gov/resource/frdcstdy.zairecountrystud00medi_0/?sp=321) explains how Mobutu's Zaire became a consumer of French products (from military to telecommunications), with Giscard d'Estaign securing in mining concessions.
- [The rise and decline of the Zairan state](https://books.google.es/books?id=R5pJxgosjIIC&pg=PA375&lpg=PA375&dq=thomson-csf+zaire&source=bl&ots=t44NYDdu3N&sig=SLjNbILDM4TN5Z9kzaZI8zNO6U0&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHj-D2lPrLAhUJNxQKHfLtBMcQ6AEIOjAE#v=onepage&q=thomson-csf%20zaire&f=false) insists in the issue, explaining also how some of d'Estaign relatives were managers of some of the French business benefited from those gestions (aren't coincidences delightful).

Then, when Mobutu's regime faced [internal revolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaba_I), guess which country was among the most active repressing it? In this first stallement, France did mostly supply (vital) logistical aid. Later on, in a bloodier [repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaba_II), it send French troops with the direct objective of ending the rebellion. Page 252 of "Zaire, a case study" tells how the Belgian, seeing their influence diminish in favor of the French (the Belgian had also sent troops, but not directly to fight the rebellion) offered to create a local alliance to protect Mobutu (remember, a dictator) from further rebellions.

Similarly, France was one of the last countries to pressure Mobutu into resigning; even when USA and Belgium were cutting relationships and imposing economic sanctions France still tried to cling to it ("Zaire, a country study p.256)

Further examples are mentioned in the [Wikipedia about neocolonialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neocolonialism#Fran.C3.A7afrique)

And yes, as a mentioned earlier, some people can claim things like "France was not supporting Mobutu but fighting communism" (but then why did not the USA or UK take part) or that "Mobutu was not just a French puppet but was playing with USA, Belgium and France" or even that some things Mobutu did were against French interest (there was a nationalization in the 70s); by its own tenuous nature (better to deal with a corrupt dirigent than afford the cost -economical and political- of invading the whole country) it is harder to see the relationships in Neocolonialism than with classical Colonialism.

Comment: Holy ****, I think I pee'd a little reading this. I just found a term: Predatory Investments. I feel like it sums things up quite well. Im starting to see the bigger picture and I am more able to put some of this together. I really appreciate all the help. from both you and user4012. The Smedly Butler guy is an interesting read.

Comment: Preventing someone from stealing what you own, fair and square, isn't "exploitation". It's resisting robbery. So, Chile and Egypt aren't valid examples. All your other examples are older than 50 years old, and while they did happen, the question was about present tense, not about what happened in history.

Comment: @user4012 countries are sovereign, so expropiation (while done following the country law) is, by definition, not "stealing". And there are international tribunals to settle the just value of the expropiated assets (as UK and France discovered when the USA and URSS stopped their "Egyptian adventure"). As you said, it is in the interest of the nation owing the resources to have them exploited, but it is also in its interest getting a fair price of it and not one negotiated by a corrupt government.

Comment: @SJuan76 - by your logic, anything Pinochet did (which was legal by Chile's law) is OK as well {{let's not even go into Godwin territory here}}. Popularly-supported and locally-legally approved robbery is still robbery; and the country being robbed is under no obligation to continue supporting the government which perpetrates it.

Comment: And yes, the examples are old but that allows to present them in a more objective way. Talking about French and Belgian support to Mobutu in Zaire or why France supported Rwanda president Habyarimana while USA and UK were more friendly to insurgent leader Paul Kagame would probably lead to a too lengthy discussion.

Comment: @user4012 not to piss Godwin, but at Numerberg Trials it became stablished that certains crimes were not excusable by the laws of the country (the whole "due obedience" argument). Yes, enactment has been lacky (*vae victis*), but the legal precedent exists. Also, Pinochet's analogy is flawed; the missing persons were not duly judged and executed but just went "missing", making the perpetrators criminals even with Pinochet's law. And even with that, there was need to find a legal justification to void an amnesty law to process Pinochet(some charges due to corruption after he left dictatorship).

Comment: @SJuan76 - I would probably appreciate Mobutu example (if you can document it properly) far more than currently posted ones.

Comment: @user4012 there you go, sorry for the delay but I thought that you would want some extensive explanations.

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on how you define the meaning of the word <strike>"is"</strike> "exploit".

Some ways in which developer world countries interact with some developing world countries that may be viewed as "exploitation" (especially from Marxist or liberal perspective):

- Many developing countries lack the industrial infrastructure to properly use their natural resources. As such, their main export is the raw natural resource - which sometimes can be very cheap relative to the added value of finished product that the raw resource is used for.

  Of course, people issuing this critique fail to notice that the alternative to "Developed country buys cheaper raw resrouce from developed country, and earns money by processing it and selling end result" isn't "developed country makes more money". The alternative is "developed country has less demand to sell its raw resource, and makes even less money - and STILL lacks the industrial capacity to process the resource itself".
- Somewhat related, the actual work of extracting the resources is frequently done by developed-world-based companies, who of course earn the profit for that work.

  Of course, people issuing this critique fail to notice that the alternative to "developed country company invests into infrastructure for resource extraction and then profits from that work" isn't "developed country earns those profits". The alternative is "developed country can't build its own resource extraction infrastructure, lacking expertise or finances; and thus has no infrastructure to earn profits off of - OR for that matter, enough resources to sell".

  Additional problem is that the developing country has other benefits from this kind of "exploitation" - from knowledge transfer to the developing country when local workers are employed in the infrastructure; to boost to economy from that infrastructure, to tax revenues.
- Developing countries act as net importers of "cheap" labour, where their populace is paid far less for their labour in absolute value than equivalent worker would be in developed country.

  Of course, people issuing this critique fail to notice that (1) the reason for cheaper labour costs is far more the lower cost of living in developed country than anything else and (2) the alternative to "Developed country exports cheap manual jobs to developed country, and they pay less than they did in developed country" isn't "developed country pays same for labour in developing country". The alternative is "developed country employs its own citizens paying them that high labour value; while developed country has no jobs to help grow their economy and help their populace".

  More importantly, the fail to notice the long term trend - the export of cheap labour is just the START. What happens next is, the developed country's economy improves and grows, it develops its own industries and internal demand, and its economy moves towards more self sufficiency. In some cases, the standards of living and thus wages there raise to the point where it starts to EXport cheap labour as well as machinery, like developed countries do (China being a good example).
- Developed countries tend to enforce their values on developing countries as condition on accepting economic help (loans from IMF etc...)

  Of course, (1) nobody's forcing any country to accept said help; (2) most of those values are long term advantageous to the recipient country - rule of law, low corruption, sound financial system and democracy are highly correllated to raised standards of living.
- Developed countries syphon off the best members of societies - what used to be called "brain drain" when applied to USSR's best and brightest choosing to emigrate to the West.

  While a real phenomenon, it isn't really a planned policy aimed at improverishing developing countries specifically - USA is just as happy to poach best minds from UK and France as from any developing country. It simply happens to affect developing countries more due to lower opportinities there.

Comment: I've tried to write a comprehensive asnwer and kinda gave up after 5 bullets. I guess people VTCing as "too broad" had a point.

Comment: I understand its broad. This is more or less the answer I was looking for and you worded where I can understand it! thanks! My only other request is if you could point me towards some direction regarding some Ideas I could research? I will look into the brain drain idea you mentioned. Thanks again.